# TinyMCE Return Plain Text from Stored Database Value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, tinymce, ejs

I have a NodeJS/Express/MongoDB application that allows users into add blog posts using TinyMCE rich text editor. The blog text is stored in a variable called blogPost, with the formatted text displayed on the 'show blog' page.

On the website homepage, I am trying to return a substring of the first blog post (e.g. first 500 characters) as a featured blog post. In my ejs template, if I use:

```
<p><%- blogs[0].blogPost %></p>
```

Then it returns the full blog post, including all the formatting. But if I add a substring to it like this:

```
<p><%- blogs[0].blogPost.substring(0,500) %></p>
```

Then it does not work correctly, as it returns the formatting data as part of the string (e.g. <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0cm; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri etc.).

How can I return only a substring of plain text from the stored value? Thanks